# blackberry CRC32 issue

Tags: java, blackberry, crc32

I've been stuck on this for a few days now and can't seem to get it. I'm hoping that by posting here, I'll have an epiphany and fix this issue 30 seconds after posting! :D
Here goes....

I need to encrypt a string, append it to my URL, and send it to the server. The steps are as follows:

```
1. Build the string (for this post, I'm using a constant TEST string)
2. Get a CRC of the string and add that to the front of the string.
3. HEX the whole string.
4. Append to URL and connect over HTTP
```

I'm stuck on 2!! The CRC that I SHOULD be getting is `1903129755`, but among other results, I'm getting `-1903129756`. NOTE: For purposes of this post, I'm using a test string and its resulting CRC. The string will change as I include the time in milliseconds when building it.

I should point out also, this is on blackberry. The android code works perfect. That CRC is taken from both the Android and an online CRC generator website:
`http://hash.online-convert.com/crc32b-generator`

The code I have seems to work for others, so I'm obviously at fault here. Can someone spot my error?? Thanks

As you can see, I've tried a few different ways:

```
    import net.rim.device.api.util.CRC32;

    public long getCrcValue(String inputText)
    {
            int crc1 = 0,crc2=0;
            long crc3=0;

            crc1 = CRC32.update(CRC32.INITIAL_VALUE, inputText.getBytes());
            crc2 = CRC32.update(0, inputText.getBytes());
            String temp = Integer.toBinaryString(crc1);
            crc3 = Long.parseLong(temp,2);
            long crc4 = CRC32.update(CRC32.INITIAL_VALUE, inputText.getBytes());
            long crc5 = CRC32.update(0, inputText.getBytes());


            logger.log("CRC1 is: "+crc1);
            logger.log("CRC2 is: "+crc2);
            logger.log("CRC3 is: "+crc3);
            logger.log("CRC4 is: "+crc4);
            logger.log("CRC5 is: "+crc5);

return crc1;
}
```

PS `logger` is my own class to output customised formatted outputs to the console, so ignore it.

EDIT: Speaking of outputs, here's what the output is:

```
CRC1 is: -1903129756
CRC2 is: -460833676
CRC3 is: 2391837540
CRC4 is: -1903129756
CRC5 is: -460833676
```

EDIT2: Here's the equivalent Android code.
Note `crc` is defined as `CRC32 crc`:

```
public long getCrcValue(String inputText)
{
    crc.reset();
    crc.update(inputText.getBytes());
    return crc.getValue();
}
```

Comment: What is the equivalent Android code that you are using?

Comment: From some reason your output CRC is the bit inverse of your expected value, so unless you find a solution, you may just invert your output

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are calling this "encrypting" the string. CRC32 has no cryptographic strength. Even if it did, prepending the checksum to the string and hex encoding the whole thing has no cryptographic strength.

Comment: @Oli I've put up the Android code there.

Comment: @Hasturkun Ye I noticed that. But I'm using the RIM code samples so I figure I must be doing something wrong!

Comment: @Richard I said I had to encrypt a string to send to the server. The CRC will be part of that string to be encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI,
Eventually I fixed this by taking the source from `java.util.zip.CRC32` and `java.util.zip.checksum` and creating new classes in my blackberry project using that source. Since thats the same implementation that Android uses, both apps work fine!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it should be:

```
int crc32 = CRC32.update(CRC32.INITIAL_VALUE, inputText.getBytes()) ^ 0xffffffff;
```

Comment: That works thanks!! Oddly enough, CRC32.INITIAL_VALUE is equal to 0XFFFFFFFF! I've never used `^` before. Can someone explain what its used for? I'm guessing some sort of binary multiplication?

Comment: Sorry. I should have pointed out, that example CRC was only a test one. The CRC will be changing constantly because I'm including the time in milliseconds. While this works for that one CRC, its not working for the others and I am still getting negative CRCs. Am I using CRC32.update() wrong??

Comment: @eoinzy: for a 32 bit value `^` (XOR) `0xffffffff` is the same as NOT

Answer (score 0):

```
String temp = Integer.toBinaryString(crc1);
crc3 = Long.parseLong(temp,2);
```

Off topic but what on earth is that? Are you trying to do 'long crc3 = crc1;' the hardest possible way?

Comment: I was converting the CRC to binary, coz I figured the root of the problem was to do with the first digit of an 8-bit binary int (10101010) representing signing (+/-) so converting it to binary would be 0000000010101010 so then the leading digit is 0 all the time. Remember, i kept getting a negative number for my CRC when it should have been positive. I suppose its obvious now I'm a newb when it comes to binary mathematics!!